# How to determine the character set used by Windows in Taiwanese?

Tags: windows-7, character-encoding, chinese, character-set

I'm using a Windows 7 Home in **Taiwanese** at work, and knowing the character set that is being used would be of invaluable importance to me.

- How to determine the character set used by Windows in Taiwanese?

I've read that `Microsoft Code page 950` is a famous variant of `Taiwan Big5` character encoding ([wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Character_encoding#Common_character_encodings)), but I want to be sure.

If helps, here's a screenshot of the default font used in notepad: (image copied from [this original link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8GxDb.png)):

[image: default font used in notepad]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By [National Language Support (NLS) API Reference](https://www.microsoft.com/resources/msdn/goglobal/default.mspx?OS=Windows%20Vista), *Chinese (Taiwan)* LCID/Culture Identifier is `0x0404` (= `1028` in decimal). `OEM` code page as well as `ANSI` code page is `950`. You could convince oneself about this fact with PowerShell command

```
Get-Culture | Format-Custom -Property TextInfo
```

or, if Chinese (Taiwan) *is not* your system locale:

```
[System.Globalization.CultureInfo]::GetCultureInfo(0x0404) | `
    Format-Custom -Property TextInfo
```

**Output**:

```
class CultureInfo
{
  TextInfo = 
    class TextInfo
    {
      ANSICodePage = 950
      OEMCodePage = 950
      MacCodePage = 10002
      EBCDICCodePage = 500
      LCID = 1028
      CultureName = zh-TW
      IsReadOnly = True
      ListSeparator = ,
      IsRightToLeft = False
    }
}
```

Another Microsoft article calls code page `950` as [Traditional Chinese Big5](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/goglobal/cc305155).